# Niveau von Relativsatz “Hier ist die Datei, worauf du wartest”

Tags: usage

Hier ist ein typischer Relativsatz:

> (a) Hier ist die Datei, auf die du wartest.

Man kann auch ein wo-Kompositum benutzen:

> (b) Hier ist die Datei, worauf du wartest.

Wie klingt (b), verglichen mit (a)? Ist es formeller oder informeller, und würde man das im Alltagsgespräch sagen?

Comment: Soweit ich weiß, ist (b) falsch.

Comment: http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2014/07/29/wo-compounds-worauf-woraus-wovon-meaning-german/   Die zweite Häfte gibt einen Einblick, wann ein wo-Wort angebracht ist, und warum in diesem Fall hier nicht.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Wort „worauf“ kann verschiedene Bedeutungen haben. In *Duden Band 10 – Bedeutungswörterbuch* findet man die folgende Auflistung:

> **worauf** <Pronominaladverb>:
>
> 1. <interrogativ>
>    a) auf welche Sache?: worauf kommt es hier an? *sinnv.:* auf was.
>    b) auf welcher Sache?: worauf liegst du? *sinnv.:* auf was.
> 2. <relativisch>
>    a) auf welche (eben erwähnte) Sache: das Geld, worauf ich warte. *sinnv.:* auf das.
>    b) auf welcher (eben erwähnten) Sache: der Stuhl, worauf er sitzt. *sinnv.:* auf dem.
>    c) auf welchen (eben erwähnten) Vorgang folgend: ich gab ihm den Brief, worauf er das Zimmer verließ.

Hier trifft der Fall 2 a) zu. Beide in der Frage genannten Sätze sind somit korrekt:

> Hier ist die Datei, auf die du wartest.
> Hier ist die Datei, worauf du wartest.

Allerdings wird in *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* erklärt, dass der relativische Gebrauch der mit wo[r]- gebildeten Pronominaladverbien mehr und mehr zurückgeht.
Überwiegend – insbesondere bei Personen – wird die Verbindung Präposition + Relativpronomen gebraucht und auch vom Duden empfohlen:

> Das ist die Welt, in der wir leben.
> *selten:* Das ist die Welt, worin wir leben.
>
> Dies ist der Wagen, mit dem sie flüchteten.
> *selten:* Dies ist der Wagen, womit sie flüchteten.
>
> Die große Sorgfalt, mit der hier gearbeitet wird.
> *selten:* Die große Sorgfalt, womit hier gearbeitet wird.
>
> Die Leute, von denen ich euch erzählte, sind eingezogen.
> *nicht:* Die Leute, wovon ich euch erzählte, sind eingezogen.
>
> Das ist eine Vorgesetzte, auf die man zählen kann.
> *nicht:* Das ist eine Vorgesetzte, worauf man zählen kann.

Dementsprechend sollte auch im in der Frage dargestellten Fall die Verbindung Präposition + Relativpronomen vorzuziehen sein:

> Hier ist die Datei, auf die du wartest.
> *selten:* Hier ist die Datei, worauf du wartest.

Wenn jedoch kein Bezugswort vorhanden ist, dann wird das Pronominaladverb vorgezogen:

> Das ist alles, worum ich Sie bitte.
> *selten:* Das ist alles, um was ich Sie bitte.
>
> Es gibt manches, wozu ich mehr Lust hätte.
> *selten:* Es gibt manches, zu dem ich mehr Lust hätte.

Comment: Interessant, was der Duden so schreibt. Ich finde, der relativische Gebrauch ist so selten, dass ich glatt sagen würde, b) ist eine Formulierung, wo falsch ist. ;-)