# „Womit“ versus „mit welchem“ als Relativpronomen

Tags: word-choice, pronoun, relative-clause

Ist es möglich Folgendes zu sagen:

> das Auto, **womit** ich in den Urlaub gefahren bin

Oder ist nur Folgendes zulässig?

> das Auto, **mit welchem** ich in den Urlaub gefahren bin

Comment: Related: [Niveau von Relativsatz “Hier ist die Datei, worauf du wartest”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/18005/9551)

Comment: Mein erster Gedanke war 'Das Auto,  mit dem ich...'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Möglich sind alle drei Varianten:

> Das Auto, mit **dem** ich in den Urlaub gefahren bin.
>
> Das Auto, womit ich in den Urlaub gefahren bin.
>
> Das Auto, mit welchem ich in den Urlaub gefahren bin.

Am häufigsten wird die erste Variante (*mit dem*) verwendet, sie klingt am natürlichsten. Stark im Rückzug, und [laut dieser Antwort selbst vom Duden nicht mehr empfohlen](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/18008/15318) ist die Variante mit *womit*, wobei man ihr ein etwas gehobeneres Register unterstellen könnte. *Mit welchem* wird stilistisch als unschön wahrgenommen, was auch für *welches* als Relativpronomen ohne Präposition gilt – es wird fast ausschließlich verwendet um das Zusammentreffen zweier gleicher Wörter zu vermeiden:

> Das Auto, das das Kennzeichen trägt.
>
> Das Auto, *welches* das Kennzeichen trägt.

Comment: Also ist "Das Auto, womit ich in den Urlaub gefahren bin." wirklich grammatikalisch richtig?

Comment: @kim366 Ja, aber weniger üblich. (Trotzdem üblicher als *mit welchem*.)

Comment: mit welchem ist sehr ublich, zumindest in Osterreich, jedoch habe ich womit noch nie gehort. Zwei Deutschlehrer sind sich daruber uneinig

Comment: @kim366 Spannend; dann denke ich, dass wir noch eine Antwort von Hubert erwarten können ;)

Comment: „Womit“ hätte ich in Schwaben verortet.

Comment: @Carsten S, ich sage auch als Schwabe 'mit dem'.

Comment: @Iris, Danke. Ich hatte an das anscheinend universelle schwäbische Relativpronomen „wo“ gedacht, aber das ist natürlich etwas anders.

Comment: @CarstenS *wo* ist in Bayern genau so universell … Warum hast du nicht daran gedacht? ;)

Comment: @Jan, weil ich schwäbische (und Badener) WG-Mitbewohner hatte, aber keine bayerischen ;) **IANAL**inguist

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

> Das Auto, mit dem ich in Urlaub gefahren bin.

Comment: Why? Can you explain this for non-native speakers?